# Links in Fixed Footer not clickable

Tags: html, css, scroll, z-index, footer

I am working on an site where I made an fixed footer which I never did before. I got the basic code from this tutorial: http://tutorialzine.com/2013/08/slideout-footer-css/ the links work in there but as my site also got an Fixed header It messes up a bit. The links arent hoverable or clickable. **How can I make my links clickable** It is not that they worked when I even copyd the code in to check if the links would work then they didnt either.

Header:

```
<header>
            <nav>
            <div class="FSG-box">
                <img id="FSG-logo" src="imgs/FSG.png"/>
            </div>
            <ul class="menu">
                <a href=""><li><strong>Home</strong></li></a>
                <a href=""><li>partners</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>education</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>about</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>contact</li></a>
            </ul>
            </nav>
        <section id="intro">

            <div class="transparent">           
        </div>
        <div class="boxhome">
        <h1>Welcome at the Food Safety Group</h1>
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
        </section>

</header>
```

Header CSS:

```
    section {
        overflow: hidden; height: 900px;
    }

    nav{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 10000;
    }
    .menu{
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        right: 100px;
        top:15px;
    }

    .menu li:hover 
    {
        -webkit-transform:scale(1.3);
    transform:scale(1.3);
    }

    .menu li{
        color: #000;
        font-weight: 300;
        list-style: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 25px;
        font-size: 18px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    transition: all 0.7s ease;
 }


    #FSG-logo{
        position: absolute;
        top:13px;
        left:13px;
        max-width:450px;
    }


    .transparent {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #000;
        opacity: 0.625;
        filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

    }

    .boxhome:hover{
        -webkit-transform:scale(1.05);
    transform:scale(1.05);
    height: 100%;
    }


    .boxhome {
        width:100%;
        margin:0 auto;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    transition: all 0.7s ease;
    }

    #intro { 
         z-index: 10;
           /* sets it above .slide1  */
        /* this pushes it below .slide1 in the scroll */
        min-height:1100px;
        max-height: 1200px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top:0;

        background: url(../imgs/kassen.jpg);
    }

        #intro h1 {
            font-size: 36pt;
            text-align:center;
            position: relative;
            font-weight: 400;
            top:320px;
        }
```

Footer + Div above HTML:

```
    <article class="result">
                    <div class="transparent2">

                    </div>
                    <div class="power">
                    <h2>The result of a well organized group</h2>
                    <h3>The six partners in this group can supply all automation required to produce a plant, harvest the product and supply the product safe and sound to the supermarket.</h3>
                    </div>
    </article>
<footer>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p class="home">Where to Find Us</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Visser Horti Systems</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Postoffice box 5103</a></li>
                <li><a href="">3295 ZG 's-Gravendeel</a></li>
                <li><a href="">The Netherlands</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="services">Sign up for our News Letter</p>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">3D modeling</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web development</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mobile development</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web &amp; Print Design</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="reachus">Reach us</p>

            <ul>
                <li><a  style="cursor: pointer;" href="http://www.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&amp;hl=nl&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=117943608112586518975.00000111c1da021ca60eb&amp;om=1&amp;t=h&amp;z=17&amp;ll=51.787568" target="_blank">Google Maps</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Phone: +31 (0) 78 673 9800</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fax: +31 (0) 78 673 3434</a></li>
                <li><a href="mailto:info@visser.eu">info@visser.eu</a></li>


            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>

</footer>
```

Footer CSS:

```
.result {
    min-height: 750px;
width: 100%;
left: 0px;
position: absolute;
background: url('../imgs/result.jpg') no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
top: 2830px;
z-index:1;
}

footer{
    height:400px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index:-2;
    background-color: #303030;

}


footer > ul{
    width:50%;
    position:fixed;
    left:50%;
    bottom:0;
    margin-left:-480px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    z-index:-1;
}

footer > ul > li{

    width:33.3%;
    float:left;
}

footer ul{
    list-style: none;
}

/* The links */

footer > ul > li ul li{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:1.8;
}

footer > ul > li ul li a{
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

footer > ul > li ul li a:hover{
    color:#fff !important;
}

footer a.logo{
    color: #fff !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

footer a.logo i{
    font-style: normal;
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    display: block;
    left: 48px;
    top: 18px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
}

footer a.logo:before{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('../img/sprite.png') no-repeat -19px -70px;
    width: 48px;
    height: 37px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}

footer p{
    width: 90%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    padding: 9px 0;
    line-height: 18px;
    background-color: #058cc7;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    opacity:0.9;
    cursor:default;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s;
    transition: opacity 0.4s;
}

footer > ul > li:hover p{
    opacity:1;
}

footer p:before{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('../img/sprite.png') no-repeat;
    width: 16px;
    height: 18px;
    margin: 0 12px 0 15px;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

footer p.home{
    background-color: #F58020;
}

footer p.home:before{
    background-position: 0 -110px;
}

footer p.services{
    background-color: #F58020;
}

footer p.services:before{
    background-position: 0 -129px;
}

footer p.reachus{
    background-color: #F58020;
}

footer p.reachus:before{
    background-position: 0 -89px;
}
```

Comment: Please paste a link to a demo.

Comment: Already was working on one btw **NOTE** I know putting the `z-index: -2;` to `1` works but i need it to styill be sliding under the div

Comment: http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2013/08/slideout-footer-css/ best demo but with the working links i tried making a fiddle but pretty new to that and it looked pretty messed up @Jay

Comment: Sorry im not following what you require here? it seems fine to me, you do not have a fixed footer?

Comment: College came  up with a fix but the problem was that my links in my fixed footer couldnt be clicked cause of the z-index on it a invisible div floated over it so nothing could be selected or clicked. I gave all the other "BIG" divs a z-index and somehow it made my links clickable thanks for your time though

Answer (score 1):

`z-index`on all divs like the `.result` fixed the problem

Comment: This solved my problem after some annoyance. I am leaving a comment to encourage asking questions like this. New programmers to CSS will find this useful in my opinion.